# Rounding score on 2 decimals in sort - SOLR 4.2

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

How to round score of search result on 2 decimals?

Can I use, rounded score in sort?

I need somethink like:

```
/?q=term&sort=round(score, 2) desc, orders desc
```

in Solr version 4.2

I want to sort search result by field *orders*, but I got not relevant result first. I got a few thousand results. So, I want to make compromise between field *orders* and *score*.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Scores are only relevant in comparison to other scores of the same query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function Queries require an indexed field and `score` is not a real field, thus you can't use it. But I like femtoRgon's approach. Here is an other version

You could use rint()/product() in combination with [query()](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#query)

```
q=rint(product(query({!v="author:alice"}) ,100))&defType=func&fl=*,score&sort=score desc, author desc
```

Substitue *author:alice* with your query. I am not sure what the performance impact is, since it runs subqueries. You will have to check that.

Comment: Yes, femtoRgon's approach is very nice, but it can not be applied.

Comment: What I liked is the combination with rint() and product(), since there is no round() function query. Is the query() solution working for you?

Comment: I used query() function with rint(), but that didn't work well. Now with product() approach works exelent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `round` [function query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) that I'm aware of, but there is `rint` which rounds to an int, which I believe you could use like:

```
sort=rint(product(score,100)) desc, orders desc
```

Comment: I got an error "sort param could not be parsed as a query...". I Thinks that can not use score in sort functions? Are you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default solr QueryComponent use [scorePrecisionComponent](http://newsolr.blogspot.in/2015/06/solr-score-rounding-custom-component.html) which will chop off the extra precision and give more weight on your sort condition.
You can change the score precision to your desired value by configuring the  solr param (scorePrecision).